# ionic4 [ERROR] Please use ionic generate service for generating service providers

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

> ionic g provider [name]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYJpV.png)

then I seek for help `ionic g --help` so it giving me these examples

Examples:

```
    $ ionic g 
    $ ionic g page
    $ ionic g page contact
    $ ionic g component contact/form
    $ ionic g component login-form --change-detection=OnPush
    $ ionic g directive ripple --skip-import
    $ ionic g service api/user
```

Comment: what you want to achieve ? Want to create a service provider?

Answer (score 3):

According to official documentation of ionic [v3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/cli/generate/) and [v4](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/generate) for generate cli you have to use the below commands to generate a service/provider for respective version.

Ionic v3

```
ionic generate provider [service/provider name] 
ionic g provider [service/provider name]
```

Ionic V4

```
ionic generate service [service/provider name] 
ionic g service [service/provider name]
```